# how do we create expandable rows with same column as parents, and there can be multiple child rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

[image]

As can be seen on above image, when clicking on the expand button the row will expand and it can have multiple child rows. All these child rows will have same

I tried with below code but the problem it is not expanding all child rows, its only expanded next child row.

```js
const expandButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');
const parentRows = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');

expandButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    parentRows[index].classList.toggle('expanded');
    let childRow = parentRows[index].nextSibling;
    while (childRow && !childRow.classList?.contains('parent')) {
      if (childRow.classList?.contains('child')) {
        childRow.classList.toggle('show');
      }
      childRow = childRow.nextSibling;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.child {
  display: none;
}

.parent.expanded+.child {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td><button class="expand">Expand</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>Child Row 1-1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>Child Row 1-2</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>Child Row 1-3</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Your code is almost correct, but you need to change the CSS selector in your style to reflect the class show you're toggling in your JavaScript code.

Update the CSS to the following:
`<style>
.child {
  display: none;
}

.child.show {
  display: table-row;
}
</style>`
Now, when you click the "Expand" button, all the child rows related to the parent row should be expanded or collapsed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution for this kind of task would be extremely complicated, so I suggest you to check out some popular UI library, such as Bootstrap.

Follow the guide https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/#cdn-via-jsdelivr

Put this to your HTML:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then, you may check out this working code https://codepen.io/n3k1t/pen/OJMGgyq